# I am trying to create a new VM in Azure and getting validation error as "Network interfaces should not have public IPs"

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I am trying to create a new VM in Azure and getting validation error as "Network interfaces should not have public IPs". I am just trying to create a Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS with all the default options selected. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong here.

Error Details:

{"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","message":"The template deployment failed because of policy violation. Please see details for more information.","details":[{"code":"RequestDisallowedByPolicy","target":"ubuntuvm62","message":"Resource 'ubuntuvm62' was disallowed by policy. (Code: RequestDisallowedByPolicy)","additionalInfo":[{"type":"PolicyViolation","info":{"policyDefinitionDisplayName":"Network interfaces should not have public IPs","evaluationDetails":{"evaluatedExpressions":[{"result":"True","expressionKind":"Field","expression":"type","path":"type","expressionValue":"Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces","targetValue":"Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces","operator":"Equals"},{"result":"False","expressionKind":"Field","expression":"Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/ipconfigurations[*].publicIpAddress.id","path":"properties.ipConfigurations[*].properties.publicIpAddress.id","expressionValue":"/subscriptions/8f2bfae4-37f5-44fe-94b5-6e16ff8040f4/resourceGroups/ubunturesourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/ubuntuvm-ip","targetValue":"*","operator":"NotLike"}]},"policyDefinitionId":"/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/83a86a26-fd1f-447c-b59d-e51f44264114","policyDefinitionName":"83a86a26-fd1f-447c-b59d-e51f44264114","policyDefinitionEffect":"deny","policyAssignmentId":"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/258ac4e4-146a-411e-9dc8-79a9e12fd6da/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/b8ff9a106bbe41f7be986f29","policyAssignmentName":"b8ff9a106bbe41f7be986f29","policyAssignmentDisplayName":"Network interfaces should not have public IPs","policyAssignmentScope":"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/258ac4e4-146a-411e-9dc8-79a9e12fd6da","policyAssignmentParameters":{}}}],"policyDetails":[{"isInitiative":false,"assignmentId":"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/258ac4e4-146a-411e-9dc8-79a9e12fd6da/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/b8ff9a106bbe41f7be986f29","assignmentName":"Network interfaces should not have public IPs","viewDetailsUri":"https://portal.azure.com#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/EditAssignmentBladeV2/assignmentId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Management%2FmanagementGroups%2F258ac4e4-146a-411e-9dc8-79a9e12fd6da%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyAssignments%2Fb8ff9a106bbe41f7be986f29"}]}]}

Answer (score 1):

Someone that owns your subscription has created a policy that doesn't allow for public IP addresses.

"The template deployment failed because of policy violation."